# VBA PowerPoint slide Title

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working on a custom tool that generates customized Instructor notes for a given presentation.  I am having a problem where I am processing a presentation where a slide basically has no Title object on it Then I run through the code it is bi-passing my if statements with .

I have reduced the code to the basics to make it as easy as possible.

My test lesson has a normal slide with the text place holder filled out, the next slide is a logo slide with no title text box, just a copyright information and logo, (this is the slide that is having issues) and then another slide where the title place holder is present, but left blank.

How do I check the individual slide to make sure that the title placeholder exists?

```
Public Sub GetTitle()
    Dim pres As Presentation    'PowerPoint presentation
    Dim sld As Slide            'Individual slide
    Dim shp As Shape            'EIAG Text Shape
    Dim ShpType As String       'Shape Type
    Dim SldTitle As String      'Slide TITLE

    'Go through each slide object
    Set pres = ActivePresentation
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides.Range
    On Error Resume Next
        If sld.Shapes(1).PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderCenterTitle Or sld.Shapes(1).PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderTitle Then
            If sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange <> "" Then
                SldTitle = sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange
                Debug.Print SldTitle & " - Slide: " & CStr(sld.SlideNumber)
            Else
                Debug.Print "BLANK TITLE - Slide: " & CStr(sld.SlideNumber)
            End If
        Else
            ShpType = sld.Shapes.Item(1).Type
            Debug.Print ShpType & "Not Processed There is no Title object"
        End If
    Next sld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the HastTitle method of the Shapes Collection to check if a slide has a title placeholder:

```
If sld.Shapes.HasTitle then
```

You should also not rely on the title placeholder being shape 1 and rather loop through all shapes on the slide, checking each one as follows:

```
Option Explicit

' Function to return an array of title texts from a presentation
' Written by Jamie Garroch at http://youpresent.co.uk
' Inputs : None
' Outputs : Array of title strings
Function GetTitlesArr() As Variant
  Dim oSld As Slide
  Dim oShp As Shape
  Dim iCounter As Integer
  Dim arrTitles() As String
  For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
      With oShp
        If .Type = msoPlaceholder Then
          Select Case .PlaceholderFormat.Type
            Case ppPlaceholderCenterTitle, ppPlaceholderTitle
              ReDim Preserve arrTitles(iCounter)
              arrTitles(iCounter) = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
              iCounter = iCounter + 1
          End Select
        End If
      End With
    Next
  Next
  GetTitlesArr = arrTitles
End Function
```

Comment: This worked perfectly Thank you.  I was not sure about the title being shape 1, I read it on the MSDN website so I thought it was a built in function of PowerPoint, but you are right, better safe then sorry. if it accurate or if MS changes something then it will still perform the Job,  Once again, thanks